# 1062 Duplicate entry '15-1' for key 'virtuemart_product_id'

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

When I try to make data migration from VirtueMart 1.1.x to VirtueMart 2 i've got an error: An error has occurred. 1062 Duplicate entry '15-1' for key 'virtuemart_product_id.

Can someone, please, help me, step by step? I'm new with the virtuemart plugin.
Thanks

Comment: I think you will find the community at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange to be a more tolerant / friendly group of volunteers.  Please join us and post your Joomla-centric questions there.

Answer (score 0):

this means that you are trying import data to database table but it just includes such data with such ID yes. So before importing, be sure the table is empty.